# Rebuild each table row as a definition list using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I successfully converted my table to Objects using the $.map function. However, I want to convert `<tr> to <dl> <th> to <dt> <td> to <dd>`then append the result on the page & finally hide the original table from view.

**Note**: The actual number of rows will vary on each table. I'm assuming that all tables on the site will have a `thead`

### HTML:Desired Result

```
<div id="item">
    <dl>
      <dt>First Name:</dt>
      <dd>James</dd>
      <dt>Last Name:</dt>
      <dd>Matman</dd>
      <dt>Job Title:</dt>
      <dd>Chief Sandwich Eater</dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
      <dt>First Name:</dt>
      <dd>The</dd>
      <dt>Last Name:</dt>
      <dd>Tick</dd>
      <dt>Job Title:</dt>
      <dd>Crimefighter Sorta</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

### HTML: Current

```
<div id="item"></div>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Job Title</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>James</td>
        <td>Matman</td>
        <td>Chief Sandwich Eater</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>The</td>
        <td>Tick</td>
        <td>Crimefighter Sorta</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### JQuery

```
var rowCount = $("tbody > tr").length;
var items = [];
var headers = [];

$("thead th").each(function() {
     headers.push($(this).text());
});

var tbl = $('table tbody tr').map(function(r) {
 return $(this).find('td').map(function(c) {
     return {
         row:r + 1,
         col:c + 1,
         cell: $(this).text()
     }
 }).get();
}).get();

console.log(tbl);
//$("#item").html(JSON.stringify(items));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:-

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hMN8/)

```
//Get the template from table headers.
var template = $("<dl>");
$("table thead tr th").map(function () {
    return $('<dt/>', {
        text: $(this).text()
    }).get();
}).appendTo(template); 


//Now look through the data
$("table tbody tr").each(function () {

    var newDl = template.clone(); //Clone the template
    $(this).find('td').each(function (idx, ob) {

        newDl.find('dt:nth-of-type(' + (idx + 1) + ')').after($('<dd/>', {
            text: $(this).text()
        })); //Construct the dd and find the position of dt after which this dd need to be insert, using nth-of-type.
    })
    $('#item').append(newDl); //append it to the div.
});
```

Comment: I sort of prefer this technique to my answer, particularly the template creation (I just preserved the OP's code).  Though I think mine is easier to read/comprehend.

Comment: Yeah i agree.. :) this is just using the jquery selectors. But yeah both kind of same to me.. :)

Comment: Then the OP will come back and say he really wanted the data in the `items` array instead or something.

Comment: I agree with @Orbling that I like the template creation yet the other is easier to comprehend if I go back to it in a year. Thank you to both for your help & especially commenting the code.

Answer (score 3):

It's easy enough to generate the `<dl>` list from the table, using only a small modification to your code:

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nfnrJ/5/**

```
// Create a list of headers
var headers = [];

$("thead th").each(function() {
     headers.push($(this).text());
});

// Iterate through each table row
var tbl = $('table tbody tr').each(function(cIndex, cRow) {
    // Create a new <dl> object for each row
    var cDL = $('<dl></dl>');

    // Iterate through each cell in the row
    $(cRow).find('td').each(function(cCellIndex, cCell) {
        // For each cell append the corresponding header as a <dt>
        // and then append a <dd> element with the cell text
        cDL.append('<dt>' + headers[cCellIndex] + ':</dt>')
           .append('<dd>' + $(cCell).text() + '</dd>');
    });

    // Append the new <dl> list to the #item <div>
    $('#item').append(cDL);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This was my approach:

```
var headers = []; $("thead th").each(function() {
     headers.push($(this).text()); 
});

//get the table rows (but not the header). 
$("tbody").children().each(function(index, tr){
    //create a mew dl element
    var $dl = $('<dl>');
    //add the data from each row.
    $(tr).children().each(function(index, td){
        $dl.append($('<dt>').html(headers[index] + ':'));
        $dl.append($('<dd>').html($(td).html()));  
        //append the dl element to the item div.
        $dl.appendTo('#item');
    }); 
}); 

//remove the table. 
$('table').remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/redders6600/GKsZk/1/

Comment: +1 As it's much the same as the other two - though beware using `.children()` with `<table>` objects, as some browsers alter the DOM and add group wrappers around elements, which can make direct descendant selectors fail.